# Как сделать чтобы каждые 0.5 секунд к переменной прибавлялось 1?

Tags: java, android

Как сделать чтобы каждые 0.5 секунд к переменной прибавлялось 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Функция, которая вызывается каждые 500мс и увеличивает переменную `counter` на 1:

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        counter++;
        Log.i("tag", "A Kiss every 5 seconds");
    }
}, 0, 500);
```

Понятное дело, переменная `counter` должна быть определена в доступной области видимости, например - в свойствах текущего класса.

Comment: А таймер разве не в отдельном потоке работает? Если да, то могут быть проблемы с неатомарным инкрементом.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(;;) {
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
counter++;
}
```